# NHibernate - create order

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, nhibernate

I am searching for a solution for creating an order by clause.
I have a table which has a column for created and one for changed. These two columns contains a DateTime. Changed could be null, if a record was only created and never changed.
Now I should select it with HQL all records ordered by changed desc, if changed is not null, else, if changed is null, by created desc.

Comment: Can I give you a suggestion? When you first save your entity, set the  Changed column to be the same as Created. Then you always order by Changed since it will always have a value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example, how to create order by clause in NHibernate:

```
var result = Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Users))
                    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("FirstName"))
                    .AddOrder(Order.Desc("LastName"))
                    .List<Users>();
```